# How to simplify [3a(b-c)+5][-3a(b-c)-5] by using special product?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

In simplifying $$[3a(b-c)+5][-3a(b-c)-5],$$ I used $$4(au+bv)(cu+dv)=acu^2+(ad+bc)uv+bdv^2.$$

I failed to apply the formula to the equation because  $a=3a$, $b=-3a$, $c=5$, $d=-5$, $u=(b-c)$, $v=?$

There's no value of $v$ so I tried to find other special product but it's only

$$(au+bv)(cu+dv)=acu^2+(ad+bc)uv+bdv^2$$ fit to the equation.

Comment: One factor's the negative of the other. You know how to square a binomial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $x=3a(b-c)$ and $y=5$. Then
\begin{align}[3a(b-c)+5][-3a(b-c)-5]&=(x+y)(-x-y)\\\\ &=(x+y)\cdot(-1)(x+y)\\\\
&=-(x+y)^2\\\\
&=-x^2-2xy-y^2.
\end{align}